# Flash to HTML conversion

Tags: html, flash, converters

I want to convert flash files(.swf) into HTML5. What is the way to do it? Suggestions on Stack overflow are not working. Like pixelplant and swiffy doesnt provide the exact output. * need users to enter values in the flash. but when i convert it using swiffy. it doest show the option to enter the values.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best tool to convert flash code into html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507576/what-is-the-best-tool-to-convert-flash-code-into-html5)

Comment: I did say suggestions from earlier questions are not working. i tried swiffy but not working.

Comment: I don't know the state of Flash to HTML conversion tools but for best quality code, the very best way is likely to rebuild the thing by hand. Either way, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Flash to HTML5 converter that helps make SWF files available to a larger audience.

https://developers.google.com/swiffy/

Comment: Swiffy provides almost complete html output, but i also require interacting with the HTML output. Swiffy doesnt provide AS

Comment: Dear Rushikesh Lakare, actually you can already build Rich Media ads in HTML5 ;)

https://support.google.com/richmedia/topic/2672499?rd=1

Comment: @RushikeshLakare regarding `Swiffy doesn't provide AS` yes you have to re-code that part yourself. AS3 is a C-like language (similar to C++, Java, C# etc).. How do you automatically convert C++ to HTML/JS... you can't cos different system/concepts of coding. Google has advice on differences to help you manually convert

Comment: PS: AS2 (scripted style) is closer to Javascript than AS3 (OOP style). so if your SWF has AS2 code there are auto-tools that might help online

Comment: Thanks alot VC.One and Duc Nguyen.

Comment: Last I checked (this time last year), swiffy had no audio on mobiles. Big limitation.